# If else php statement

Tags: php, html

If there is an image I want it to show along with the content, if there is no image for the content, then show nothing.  Currently, with the code below if there is no image then I get a broken image on my page. If there is an image it works great.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

```
<?php if ($totalRows_rsPress > 0) {  ?>
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/<?php echo $row_rsPress['image']; ?>" alt="Image text" /> 
<?php } elseif ($totalRows_rsPress == 0) { return "" ; } ?>
```

Comment: What is `$totalRows_rsPress`?

Comment: you want to show nothing in the other case so why you're putting an else if , treat just the case when $totalRows_rsPress > 0 isn't it !!

Comment: something failed you then => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and you're more than likely using a db here.

Comment: $totalRows_rsPress....is coming from the DB.  Thank you for the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php if ($totalRows_rsPress > 0 && isset($row_rsPress['image']) && strlen($row_rsPress['image']) > 0) {  ?>
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/<?php echo $row_rsPress['image']; ?>" alt="Image text" /> 
<?php } elseif ($totalRows_rsPress == 0) { return "" ; } ?>
```

Comment: When I add your suggestion.  I am getting blank pages back.

Comment: Try it once again please, a bracket was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the image exists:

```
if ( ! empty($row_rsPress['image']) ) {
    echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="images/' . $row_rsPress['image'] . '" alt="Image text" />';
}
```

Comment: I am going to try your suggestion here. Will keep you posted.

Comment: I get no results back.

Comment: Do you have any images to be displayed? If you get no rows being outputted, that means this condition isn't being satisfied because there are no image-paths in the DB to be displayed. Please ensure they are by entering your exact query into phpMyAdmin or the terminal and see for yourself. All this `if` is saying, basically, is *if there is an image available, show it*. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if($totalRows_rsPress > 0) : ?>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/<?=$row_rsPress['image'];?>"/>
<?php endif; ?>
```

There was no need for the elseif statement.

Without knowing what totalRows_rsPress is, I can't tell you why it might be failing that if condition..

Comment: The OP is getting the image in both cases so `$totalRows_rsPress` is greater than `0`.

Comment: I made a note of that, but until we know what $totalRows_rsPress is - or where it's coming from, then we can't really help here.

Comment: Probably safe to assume that `$totalRows_rsPress` is the number of records returned from a query. OP's problem isn't that, it's that he doesn't want to see a *broken* image being displayed on the screen when a record does not have an image to be displayed. Simply checking whether `$row_rsPress['image']` contains a value or not will do the trick.

Comment: Marcus you are correct in saying is coming from a query.  Also, I don't want to see a broken image if there is no image for the content that is also pulling from a database.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php), i.e.:

```
if (count($totalRows_rsPress) > 0) { 
echo <<< EOF
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/{$row_rsPress['image']}" alt="Image text" /> 
EOF;
}
```

Comment: This resulted in the same results I currently get with the code that I have.  I still get a broken image and I don't want anything to show if there is no image.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    try{
         if ($totalRows_rsPress > 0) {
             echo "<img class=\'img-responsive\' src=\'images/$row_rsPress['image']\' alt=\'Image text\' />"};
         } elseif ($totalRows_rsPress == 0) { return "" ; }    
    }
    catch(err) {
        //do nothing or do in case 004
    }


?>
```

Comment: You need to escape the double-quotes `...class=\"...` Also, your syntax is incorrect.

Comment: When there is no image, I get a blank page?

Comment: No, just echo some html like echo "<p>No image was found</p>"